# Hive join with distinct

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables TableA and TableB.

TableA has columns REC_NUM and ITEM_ID.
TableB has columns ITEM_ID, UNITS.

I need to take a distinct of ITEM_ID from TableA, and fetch all the
 records from TableB for every matching value of ITEM_ID from TableA with that of the ITEM_ID of TableB.

Can someone please let know I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the question :

schema of TABLEA:
REC_NUM INT,ITEM_ID INT

schema of TABLEB:
ITEM_ID INT,UNITS INT

Following query should work:

SELECT b.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM_ID FROM TABLEA) a JOIN TABLEB b ON a.ITEM_ID=b.ITEM_ID;

Comment: What happens? Does the query parse? Is the result unexpected?

Comment: @ncke query parses and gives result as per requirement.

Answer (score 1):

correct me if I am wrong

select ITEM_ID, UNITS from TableB where ITEM_ID in (select ITEM_ID from tableA)

I am not sure why you want to use distinct, should it be used with the column REC_NUM?